# Keycloak server as Eureka client

Tags: java, jboss, keycloak, netflix-eureka

I want to make my Keycloak server works as an Eureka Client. It seems that when the server starts it doesn't find the following method :

```
javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;
```

The method's class, javax.ws.rs.core.Application, is available from the following locations:

```
 jar:file:/home/vagrant/.m2/repository/javax/ws/rs/jsr311-api/1.1.1/jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar!/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.class
 jar:file:/home/vagrant/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/ws/rs/jboss-jaxrs-api_2.1_spec/2.0.1.Final/jboss-jaxrs-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar!/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.class
```

It was loaded from the following location:

```
file:/home/vagrant/.m2/repository/javax/ws/rs/jsr311-api/1.1.1/jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar
```

Do you have any idea concerning this behaviour ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to exclude jsr311-apiand include spring-boot-starter-jersey.
works fine for me with <keycloak.version>15.0.2</keycloak.version>

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you ! It worked fine for me too

Comment: you're welcome :) i was sure that will help because I spent time on it :-$ don't forget to mark as solved ;)

Comment: I imagine that you use this one https://github.com/thomasdarimont/embedded-spring-boot-keycloak-server ? Which version you're using?